# Javamail - How can I send html and text inline without attach?

Tags: html, text, jakarta-mail, inline, attachment

I would like to send a html and a text content inline, but just one appears inline, the other appears as an attached file.
My code:

```
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        String html = "<font size=\"5\">Test HTML</font>";
        String text = "Test text + html";

        BodyPart bodyparty = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyparty.setContent(text, "text/plain");
        multipart.addBodyPart(bodyparty);

        bodyparty = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyparty.setContent(html, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(bodyparty);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(user_auth, user_password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
```

Is it possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely any mail client is going to display that the way you want.  Why not embed the plain text part in the html part using <pre> or something like that?

Comment: Thank you for your help! The complete scenario that I have today is a meeting request + html + attached file. This attached file is inline with the html text. So, my idea is write other text (it can be a html text) after this attached file.
I tried embed using <pre> but it did not work. I changed this two lines:
String text = "<pre>Test text + html</pre>";
bodyparty.setContent(text, "text/html");
Is anything wrong?

Comment: Creating the proper html text isn't a JavaMail problem.  You can experiment with that in your browser.  Once you figure out how to combine the pieces of text into the correct html text, it will be easy to incorporate that into your mail message.  You just want a single Java String, in a single text/html body part.  You don't want any attachment.

Comment: Actually is the opposite. I need more than one text/html bodyparty, because the two parts of html will be separeted by an attached file.

Comment: What do you mean "separated"?  I thought you wanted the contents of the attached file displayed inline, between the two pieces of html text?  If so, I'm suggesting that you combine all three pieces into one piece of html.

Comment: Yes, you are right. By separated I mean more than one instance of bodypart. Is there a way to embed attached file into html bodypart?

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I suggested using &lt;pre&gt;.  Don't think about attached files and body parts.  Just think about html.  How would you author an html document that would display they way you want this to display?